# How to make a Shopify GraphQL query in Rails without memory issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, shopify, shopify-app

I'm using the `graphql-client` gem and `shopify_app` gem, making a query successfully like this:

```
shop.with_shopify_session do
  query = <<-GRAPHQL
    {
      shop {
        name
      }
    }
  GRAPHQL

  client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new

  Kernel.const_set(:NameQuery, client.parse(query))
  result = client.query(NameQuery)

  puts "Shop name: #{result.data.shop.name}"
end
```

*The reason for `Kernel.const_set` is because a constant is required to make this work.

The problem: Each time this executes it adds about 100MB of ram usage on server (according to Heroku metrics).

Do you know how to execute a graphql query with Shopify in Rails without the excessive memory leak?

Comment: Have you set MALLOC_ARENA_MAX on to your heroku app?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I found a gem and that solved the problem: https://github.com/mikeyhew/shopify_graphql_client

Answer (score 0):

Prior to shopify_api v9.0 the GraphQL client implementation was limited and almost unusable due to the client making dynamic introspection queries to Shopify's API. This was not only very slow but also led to unbounded memory growth.

This issue has been greatly resolved from the Shopify Side.

Previously a client was initialized with ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new:

```
client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new

SHOP_NAME_QUERY = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  {
    shop {
      name
    }
  }
GRAPHQL

result = client.query(SHOP_NAME_QUERY)
result.data.shop.name
```

Now there's no need to initialize a client so all references to ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.new should be removed and instead the client is called via ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client:

```
client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client

SHOP_NAME_QUERY = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  {
    shop {
      name
    }
  }
GRAPHQL

result = client.query(SHOP_NAME_QUERY)
result.data.shop.name
```